# How to create new tables with PHP in MySQL?

Tags: php, database, foreach, pdo

I've got a loop which goes through various products being imported. Within this loop I also have a foreach which goes through each property of the product class and assigns values from a file to the current instance's properties, to be displayed later.

```
while(true)
{
    $currentProduct = new productImport();
    $line = fgets($fileHandle);
    if($line == null)   break;

    $cells=explode('    ', $line);
    $i=0;
    foreach($currentProduct as &$ProductProperty)
    {
        if(isset($cells[$i]))
        {
            $ProductProperty = $cells[$i];
        }
        else return false;
        $i++;
    }
    $AddedProducts[]=$currentProduct;
}
fclose($fileHandle);
return true;
```

Now that I've got that working I want to change this to instead create a table, unless one already exists, based on one property of each product. More specifically, the product class contains the value $Vendor_Name;

Using PDO (PHP Database Objects), how do I create a new table named $Vendor_Name if it doesn't exist and put values in there instead of this array?

`Edit: If it helps, the first value of each instance is a unique key.`

Comment: Why create a new table for each vendor? If most of the data fields is the same for each vendor, simply have a vendor field to specify who each product "belongs" to?

Comment: Most likely because I'm a SQL noob. ;p There are some vendors with many many products and the entire product set is ~200,000 so I thought it would speed up site searches to split them up. What do you think?

Comment: If anything, splitting up like that will just slow things down. relational databases are designed to sort through data quickly. Adding your own partitioning semantics on top of the system only comes into play if your dataset becomes extremely huge (ie: millions/billions of rows). For 200k records, it's a waste of time. Add indexes to the appropriate fields (and field used in a 'where' or 'join' is a candidate) and things should fly.

Comment: I almost understand what you are saying, at least that 200k rows is no problem. If someone wants all results from a specific vendor this is a light task? Unfortunately, your last sentence goes over my head..I think. There's currently a unique vendor ID, vendor name and unique model number for each product. Does this seem like enough?

Comment: a simple `select x,y,z from sometable where x=...` is NOTHING for a database. Unless your server is underpowered and started for ram, even millions of rows will be zipped through quickly, as long as there's an index on the 'x' field.

Comment: Well that is rather comforting thanks very much. Not quite sure what to do with this question now lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has an object that will help you create a table and has an additional parameter "IF NOT EXISTS" that says "if the table not exists, then create it".

Here is a code syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" . $Vendor_Name . "` (
`media_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`filename` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`thumb` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`media_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: This is somewhat the start of being helpful :) Would you mind editing this if you know how to specifically tie this same concept in using PDO in the context of the foreach loop above?

Comment: Exactly the same principle. Just add the code I added into a $query variable and then execute mysql_query($query);

Comment: mysql_query($query) != PDO style =/

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Assuming you already have PDO initialized, just do this:

$rows = $dbh->exec($query);